# Time format in Quartz.net tables

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

The Start_time field in Database table(dbo.QRTZ_TRIGGERS) shows this value 635371706123133677

What format is this and how can it be converted to human readable format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the from the StdAdoDelegate.cs class:

```
AddCommandParameter(cmd, "triggerStartTime", GetDbDateTimeValue(trigger.StartTimeUtc));
```

And GetDbTimeValue is

```
public virtual object GetDbDateTimeValue(DateTimeOffset? dateTimeValue)
{
    if (dateTimeValue != null)
    {
        return dateTimeValue.Value.UtcTicks;
    }
    return null;
}
```

So basically [DateTimeOffset.UtcTicks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.utcticks.aspx)

And this is the code used to convert that value back:

```
public virtual DateTimeOffset? GetDateTimeFromDbValue(object columnValue)
{
    if (columnValue != null && columnValue != DBNull.Value)
    {
        var ticks = Convert.ToInt64(columnValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        if (ticks > 0)
        {
            return new DateTimeOffset(ticks, TimeSpan.Zero);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```